# How to get rid of errors while creating a new rails app on a NTFS partition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rvm, ntfs

When I create a new rails application on my NTFS partition I receive a bunch of errors. Though, with the same configuration I do not get any error when I create the project in my home directory which sits on a ext4 formatted partition.
Here is what I get.

```
$ rails new project
      create  
      create  README
      create  Rakefile
      [...]
      create  public/index.html
      create  public/robots.txt
      create  script
      create  script/rails
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1323:in `chmod': Operation not permitted - /media/ntfs/project/script (Errno::EPERM)
    from /home/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1323:in `chmod'
    from /home/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:996:in `block (2 levels) in chmod_R'
    from /home/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1433:in `preorder_traverse'
    from /home/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:994:in `block in chmod_R'
    from /home/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:993:in `each'
    from /home/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:993:in `chmod_R'
    from /home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/actions/file_manipulation.rb:132:in `chmod'
    from /home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:17:in `chmod'
    from /home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:106:in `script'
    from /home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:96:in `build'
    from /home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:210:in `create_script_files'
    from /home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
    from /home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
    from /home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/invocation.rb:124:in `block in invoke_all'
    from /home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/invocation.rb:124:in `each'
    from /home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/invocation.rb:124:in `map'
    from /home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/invocation.rb:124:in `invoke_all'
    from /home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/group.rb:226:in `dispatch'
    from /home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
    from /home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands/application.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/cli.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rails-3.1.3/bin/rails:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/rails:19:in `load'
    from /home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/rails:19:in `<main>'
```

I installed rails 3.1.3 via rvm.

```
$ rvm list
rvm rubies
=> ruby-1.9.3-p0 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.2-p290 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.2-p180 [ x86_64 ]
```

This is my general configuration.

```
$ rails -v
Rails 3.1.3
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-linux]
$ rvm -v
rvm 1.9.2
$ bundle -v
Bundler version 1.0.21
$ gem -v
1.8.11
```

I work with Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: You've mounted an NTFS partition in ubuntu? chmod doesn't work on that as ntfs uses acls, not unix-style permission bits.

Comment: Yes. I know that chmod does not work. But does this necessarily mean I cannot put my project onto the partition?

Comment: Yes your going to have a hard time getting it working correctly because of the mix between Linux tools and an NTFS (Windows) filesystem. You may run into odd permission errors or other issues because it looks like `fileutils.rb` has platform specific implementations.

Comment: Can one say that in generell a rails project's security depends on the unix file permissions set correctly?