# Cannot Create A New Rails Project Due To chmod

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, chmod

I don't know what's changed, but recently when I try to create a new Rails project I get the error

```
/home/eric/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1348:in `chmod': Operation not permitted @ chmod_internal - /mnt/Data/Code/foodFinder/bin (Errno::EPERM)
```

And if I then they to use `Rails s` to run it, I get the error

```
bin/rails:3:in `require_relative': cannot load such file -- /mnt/Data/Code/foodFinder/config/boot (LoadError)
from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

All my old projects still seem to run fine. A probable related error, however, is if I try to `init` a new git repository. For example, if I go into the foodFinder folder and run `git init` I get the error

```
error: chmod on /mnt/Data/Code/foodFinder/.git/config.lock failed: Operation not permitted
error: chmod on /mnt/Data/Code/foodFinder/.git/config.lock failed: Operation not permitted
error: chmod on /mnt/Data/Code/foodFinder/.git/config.lock failed: Operation not permitted
Initialized empty Git repository in /mnt/Data/Code/foodFinder/.git/
```

What's going on here? This is really frustrating and completely stopping me from making anything new in Rails.

Comment: The /mnt freaks me. Did you try to create a project while on a read only mounted disk?

Comment: What's the exact command(s) you ran, under which user, and in which folder?

Comment: @KaiMattern, It's because I'm on my mounted hard drive instead of trying to fit all my code on my small SSD. It's not a read only drive; I've developed on it before.

Comment: You can try a simple "touch /mnt/Data/Code/foodFinder/test.txt" and see if you get an error. Then you know that the mount is not writable for your user.

Comment: @jefflunt, The exact command I used was "Rails new foodFinder" which generates the first error. The other errors are given by the preceding inline commands

Comment: Have a look at this here, please. Looks similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8261428/how-to-get-rid-of-errors-while-creating-a-new-rails-app-on-a-ntfs-partition

Comment: If you want to dissect this problem any further, please tell us what kind of hard disk this is. I guess it is a NTFS formatted windows drive. And then this would explain the error. If it is a linux formatted drive, please do a quick "mount" to check the mount options, just to make extra sure that the thing is correctly mounted. Did you work on the drive on this computer?

Comment: @KaiMattern I did the touch (even with the same `test.txt`! Great minds, maybe) before I posted here to make sure it wasn't just a permissions issue, and I can confirm that it isn't. It *is* an NTFS disk, as I use it as a Data drive for both my Windows and Linux partitions, which are on my SSD. I've done work on it before and it's worked in the past. I even did some coding on Sunday and it was fine. It's only when attempting to use Rails that I run into this issue. I'll check the mount options now.

Comment: My data drive is mounted in fstab with the options:

    UUID=2448D25653D8E845 /mnt/Data          ntfs-3g       defaults,owner,user,gid=users,fmask=113,dmask=002 0 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a solution to my problem. The issue *was*, as KaiMattern thought, in the mount options. I needed to set the uid to me (done by adding `uid=eric` to the fstab options). Prior to that, it had been set to root by default.

I don't know how that got changed, but it's resolved my issues.

Comment: Had the same problem with ntfs partition. Thank you!